# Delete a method from Java class in a JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file, which contains some classes.

I have to remove a method from a class and need to use same jar file in my application.

I need a tool which can allow me to do these tasks.

-> open .JAR file and shows java code

-> edit the java source code and saving file

Is there any tool to do this operation ? If yes please answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jar` to unpack the archive, then locate the `.class` file that contains the method you want to remove.

Then, you can use a java decompiler to decompile to `.java` files, edit and recompile. Note though, that if the code is obfuscated, it will be hard to locate the location of the method.